# GNU Parallel to run from a webpage

Tags: php, parallel-processing, web-crawler, gnu-parallel

I am working on a demo and using GNU Parallel to run my web crawlers in parallel to help reduce the overall time. I am running it from a php file as follows:

```
<?php

   ....
   exec(" parallel -j 8 < commands.txt", $output);
   ....
?>
```

When I run this file from terminal, it works fine and does all the scraping work given in the `commands.txt` file, but the moment I try running it from a webpage (which is calling this `php` file), `parallel` gives me the following error:

```
parallel: Warning: $SHELL not set. Using /bin/sh.
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"HOME"} in concatenation (.) or string at  /usr/bin/parallel line 943.
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"HOME"} in concatenation (.) or string at   /usr/bin/parallel line 943.
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"HOME"} in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/parallel line 2207.
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"HOME"} in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/parallel line 2207.
```

Has anyone faced a similar problem and can help me with a solution to this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try shell_exec() instead?

Comment: try using `shell_exec()`

Comment: I tried with 'shell_exec' as well. Still same error.

Comment: Its working now (although still showing warning). Thanks Matt Bryant and DevZer0 for your inputs :)

Comment: `putenv('SHELL=/bin/sh');` might work to nix the warning

Answer (score 3):

GNU Parallel uses $HOME and $SHELL. $SHELL defaults to /bin/sh, but there is no default for $HOME. So set $HOME:

```
putenv('HOME=/tmp'); # Or some other place
```

You are expected to have write permissions in $HOME.

If you want to avoid the warning set $SHELL, too:

```
putenv('SHELL=/bin/sh');
```